# Does disconnecting from an SSH session kill it?

Tags: server, ssh

I disconnect frequently by lag/timeouts or similar from a machine I am connected in to via SSH and I was wondering if my sessions are still active somewhere or if they close/logout after a certain time?

If they are not disconnected, is there a way to connect back in to the session?

(FYI, this is a default install/nothing funky... SSH is in default configuration).

Comment: If you connect with ssh and start screen on the remote machine, then even in case of disconnection you can get back to the same sessione later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They timeout.

If you want to change that behaviour you can use things like `screen`. Screen is essentially a terminal session that stays running. You can get disconnected and then just reconnect and attach to the `screen` session again. It's a bit daunting at first but it's pretty handy.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen

I've personally found that adding `-o ServerAliveInterval=30` to my SSH commands helps keep a connection alive but it won't help in cases of network interruption.